# how to printf() std::this_thread::get_id() in C++?

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I've tried to cast to `void*` and use `%p`.  I've also tried `intptr_t` with a format of `%lx`.  Both times I get the "Invalid Cast" error.

I'm using `-Wall -Werror` which checks that the arguments of the `printf()` match the function's format string.  So I can't merely count on `get_id()` leaving a 4- or 8-byte value on the stack and simply printing that value as hex.

I'm using gcc version 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1) (GCC)

The OS is Fedora release 31 (Thirty One) .  The CPU is 64-bit Intel x86.

Comment: This [`std::thread::id`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/id) (the type of the object that `get_id` returns) reference should be helpful. But why do you want to use `printf` in a C++ program?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use streams:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
printf("%s\n", oss.str().c_str());
```

Comment: Or just use `std::cout` instead of `printf`.

Comment: Got my vote although the `std::endl` seems a bit unnecessary. :)

Comment: Alas, can't use cout.  The actual problem isn't printf(), exactly, but a logging function based on vsnprintf().  Given the scope of the system, the chances of rewriting that function to emulate iostreams is zero.

Comment: @SwissFrank: You may want to read up on `std::streambuf`. You can swap out the streambuf underneath `std::cout`/`std::cerr`, and your custom streambuf can then call `log_printf("%s", buf)`.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use this work-around in a logging function that had similar requirments:

```
static std::ostringstream id;
static std::string sid = id.str();

if (sid.empty())
{
    id << std::this_thread::get_id();
    sid = id.str();
}

// our code actually has a vsnprintf() 
printf("[%u:%s] %s", getpid(),  
        sid.c_str(), another_string );
```

Same mechanism as answer 1. The thread id type is quite opaque.