# cout in multithread WITHOUT LOCK in C++20

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++20

I'm writing in C++20. Here's a very simple program that asks three threads to print some string. For example, we ask thread 1 to print `"This is thread1"`, and thread 2 to print `"This is thread2"`, and thread 3 to print `"This is thread3"`.

However, I notice that in the `printThread` function that passed into threads, if we are not using a lock, we can get print results that mingle among threads. Such as `This is This thread2 is thread3`. I would like to avoid such intervening, so I wrote my code with `mutex`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
using namespace std;


mutex m_screen;
void printCnt()
{   
    lock_guard guard(m_screen);
    cout << "Func Start" << endl;
    // Fetch the thread ID of the thread which is executing this function
    thread::id threadID = this_thread::get_id();
    
    cout << "Thread [" << threadID << "] has been called " endl;
    
    
}

// g++ foo.cpp =pthread

int main(){
    thread t1(printCnt);
    thread t2(printCnt);
    thread t3(printCnt);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();

    cout << "done" << endl;
    
}
```

I wonder if there's any way that can achieve the same effect like mutex, but **without a lock**?

Comment: [std::osyncstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_osyncstream)? It may use a lock internally when it flushes to std::cout but that would still be better than locking during the streaming.

Comment: `std::osyncstream` will still use a lock of some form.

Comment: You could construct the entire string to be output, then pass that to `cout`. This would then have one function call (instead of four).

Comment: You might be able to use the atomic library in some way.

Answer (score 1):

In general this post summarizes the ideas in the comments (with examples) and also adds 1 new way

As mentioned by Dean Johnson in the comments, the standard way to do this is the [std::osyncstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_osyncstream) function and then your code will look like this

```
void printCnt()
{   
    cout << "Func Start" << endl;
    // Fetch the thread ID of the thread which is executing this function
    thread::id threadID = this_thread::get_id();
    
    osyncstream(cout) << "Thread [" << threadID << "] has been called " endl;   
}
```

You can also first generate a string that will contain your output(as was mention by 1201ProgramAlarm), and then output the entire string at once. This can be achieved using [std::stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) or [std::format](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format). As a result, the code will look something like this

```
void printCnt()
{   
    cout << "Func Start" << endl;
    // Fetch the thread ID of the thread which is executing this function
    thread::id threadID = this_thread::get_id();
    
    // stringstream ss;
    // ss << "Thread [" << threadID << "] has been called\n";
    // string output = ss.str(); 

    string output = format("Thread [{}] has been called\n", "world");//or use commented variant above

    cout << output;   
}
```

If you are allowed yo use C-style functions, you may want to use [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)(which in general is formatter + printer, but as good as I know [doesn't know how to print std::thread::id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61203655/how-to-printf-stdthis-threadget-id-in-c))

```
void printCnt()
{   
    cout << "Func Start" << endl;
    
    static int x = 0;
    x++;
    
    printf("Thread [%d] has been called\n", x); 
}
```